# How to remove all empty array inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

I have `resultant` `array` like this,

```
[["apple","banana"],[],[],[],["kiwi"],[],[]]
```

How can I remove all the empty `[]` `array`  so that my `resultant` `array` would look like this:

```
[["apple","banana"],["kiwi"]];


var array = [["apple","banana"],[],[],[],["kiwi"],[],[]];// sample array
```

Comment: use Array.prototype.filter().

Comment: you can iterate through the parent array and use the `splice()` function provided in the Array prototype.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove empty object in from an array in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884033/how-can-i-remove-empty-object-in-from-an-array-in-js)

Comment: `var array = [["apple","banana"],[],[],[],["kiwi"],[],[]].filter((x) => { return x.length})`

Comment: @KraangPrime, there is no `accepted answer` there then how it can be `duplicate?`

Comment: @DilipG - answers do not need to be accepted to be duplicates.  Often there are unaccepted solutions that work. In this case, there is a solution that will do what you ask on that page

Answer (score 16):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter out the empty arrays - see demo below:

```js
var array = [["apple","banana"],[],[],[],["kiwi"],[],[]];// sample array

var result =  array.filter(e => e.length);
console.log(result);
```

In ES5, you can omit the *arrow function* used above:

```js
var array = [["apple","banana"],[],[],[],["kiwi"],[],[]];// sample array

var result =  array.filter(function(e) { 
  return e.length;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I really wish more people coded using this syntax -- would make all that JavaScript debugging go so much easier (and faster page load times)

Answer (score 5):

The ES5 compatible code for @kukuz answer.

```js
var array = [["apple","banana"],[],[],[],["kiwi"],[],[]];// sample array

var result =  array.filter(function(x){return x.length});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry! didn't notice @Jai

Answer (score 3):

Use Array.prototype.filter() to get a new filtered array:

```js
var array = [["apple","banana"],[],[],[],["kiwi"],[],[]];
var newArr = array.filter(function(obj){
   return obj[0] !== undefined;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
var newArray = array.filter(value => JSON.stringify(value) !== '[]');
```

Comment: Thank you, works well for empty objects with `var newArray = array.filter(value => JSON.stringify(value) !== '{}');`

Answer (score 1):

the bottom_line; pass any value that is considered falsey in the filter function and it'll be filtered out

```js
const array = [["apple","banana"],[],[],[],["kiwi"],[],[]];

var result =  array.filter(e => e[0]);

console.log(result);
```