# I would like to store a row of data from a spreadsheet as a new item in an array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to store each row of data as a separate item in an array. This is the code I have so far:

```
function data() { 
  var responses = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 263')
  var data = responses.getRange(2, 2, responses.getLastRow()-1, responses.getLastColumn()-1).getValues()
  var n = []
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    n.push(row) 
    Logger.log(row)
    Logger.log(n)     
  })
}
```

At the moment, this prints each rows contents to the Logger. How would I go about storing each row's data into var `n`? I have used:

```
n.push(row)
```

but this just adds everything from the row, not just the data.

Source row

[image: This is what my data looks like]

I would like my array to look like this:

```
[1      3       4],[2   3       4], [2      4   4   6]
```

Comment: You want to retrieve the value of ``[[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,4,4,6]]`` from the spreadsheet of the image. If my understanding is correct, how about modifying to ``var n = responses.getRange(1, 1, responses.getLastRow(), responses.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(function(e){return e.filter(Number)})``? If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much! That looks fine to me but I have simplified my spreadsheet to include numbers when the real thing includes string. Would I need to change any of the formula to accommodate these changes?

Comment: I'm sorry for my incomplete comment. In that case, can you try ``e.filter(String)`` instead of ``e.filter(Number)``?

Comment: It is working, thank you! Out of curiosity, what would I need to add to the code in order to remove the blank spaces or , in the empty elements of the array?

Comment: In this script, ``e.filter(Number)`` and ``e.filter(String)`` remove the empty elements in ``e`` of an array. Was my understanding for your reply correct?

Comment: For example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884033/how-can-i-remove-empty-object-in-from-an-array-in-js

Comment: My mistake, I made some errors myself when editing the code to suit my project. You solution works perfectly fine! Thank you ever so much!

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. Can you post your latest script which resolved the issue as an answer and accept it? Because I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was the final solution to the issue as answered by @Tanaike in comments:

```
function data() {
  var fr = ...
  var data = fr.getRange(2, 2, fr.getLastRow()-1, fr.getLastColumn())
      .getValues().map(function(row) {
        return row.filter(String)
      })

  Logger.log(data)
}
```

It uses the `String` class constructor as a predicate to remove empty indexes from the source rows.